# SQL SUM error (Sums and multiplies)

Tags: sql, join, count, sum

I've got two tables similar to these:

```
TABLE1
PC   Date       Num  Name   ID
8901 01/03/2013 5099 AAA    11
8901 01/03/2013 5099 AAA    11
8901 01/03/2013 5099 AAA    11
8901 02/03/2013 5099 AAA    12
8902 03/03/2013 5099 AAA    13
8903 04/03/2013 5099 AAA    14

TABLE2
PC   Date       Num  Name ID Bar2
8901 01/03/2013 5099 AAA  11 3
8901 01/03/2013 5099 AAA  11 2
8901 01/03/2013 5099 AAA  11 9
8901 02/03/2013 5099 AAA  12 3
8902 03/03/2013 5099 AAA  13 4
8903 04/03/2013 5099 AAA  14 5
```

And this query:

```
SELECT TABLE1.PC, TABLE1.Date, TABLE1.Num, TABLE1.Name, COUNT(*), SUM(TABLE2.Bar2)          
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID         
GROUP BY TABLE1.PC, TABLE1.Date, TABLE1.Num, TABLE1.Name        
ORDER BY TABLE1.PC, TABLE1.Date
```

The result is:

```
PC      Date            Num     Name COUNT  SUM
8901    01/03/2013 0:00 5099    AAA  9      42
8901    02/03/2013 0:00 5099    AAA  1      3
8902    03/03/2013 0:00 5099    AAA  1      4
8903    04/03/2013 0:00 5099    AAA  1      5
```

So, it sums and then it multiplies by the nº of entries ((3+2+9)*3 = 42).

What am I doing wrong?
thanks!!

Comment: Why do you need to join these tables together? It appears that the column you are SUMming on is only in TABLE2 Are the columns PC, Date, Num, Name, and ID, when taken together, a UNIQUE key. I assume that you have other information in "TABLE2" that you want to display? If the five columns mentioned above are a UNIQUE key, then, you can add all of these in your WHERE clause to eliminate the duplicates which appear to be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what you want as the desired result, but you can use a subquery to get the Total Sum:

```
SELECT t1.PC, 
  t1.Date, 
  t1.Num, 
  t1.Name, 
  COUNT(*), 
  t2.Total
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT SUM(Bar2) Total, ID
  FROM TABLE2 
  GROUP BY ID
) t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.PC, t1.Date, t1.Num, t1.Name, t2.Total
ORDER BY t1.PC, t1.Date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/517f4/4)

Comment: I'm not sure yet how to put this in MS Query. The result I want in the first example (ID = 11) is COUNT = 9 instead of 3 and SUM = 14 instead of 42.